# Disable device preview options in the block editor

Tags: block-editor, previews

In a recent update to WordPress, the following responsive device preview system was added to the Block Editor:

[image: Preview]

Easy to *hide* them via:

```
.block-editor-post-preview__button-resize {
    display: none;
}
```

But, how can we *disable* this feature so when you click on the preview button, it opens up a front-end preview of the post on a new tab. Just as it used to be.

Comment: This is not yet possible; there's an existing issue for this at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/23126

Comment: You can also try this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/387527/how-to-make-the-preview-button-automatically-open-new-tab/417060#417060

Answer (score 1):

Still no way to disable them from what I can see, but the CSS you gave didn't do what I wanted, so I used this:

```
.edit-post-post-preview-dropdown .components-menu-group:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

This just keeps the 'Preview in new tab' option.