# How to make the Preview button automatically open new tab?

Tags: block-editor, previews

In the past year or so the Preview button does not automatically open the preview tab anymore, and I need to click another button to do that. Is there a way to skip this dialog?

[image]

<sub>Related: [Shortcut for preview? | WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcut-for-preview/)</sub>

Comment: To be clear, you would like to skip the dropdown show in the picture, and go straight to a desktop preview in a new tab?

Comment: yes. I think the other options are pretty useless

Answer (score 2):

The Preview button and associated functionality is currently undergoing a fair amount of iteration - I would imagine we will see a keyboard shortcut added, along with other options for modifying it's UI down the road.

## A Big Hack

Interestingly, the old direct-preview button's component is still rendered, but is hidden on a > 600px media query. We can reveal the button again with a little CSS:

```css
.edit-post-header__settings .editor-post-preview {
    display: block;
}
```

I wouldn't rely on this working indefinitely, however.

## A Little Hack

For now, the most canonical solution would probably be to register a block editor plugin which renders a new `<PostPreviewButton>` component as a child of a `<PinnedItems>` slotfill.

> It should be noted that doing this directly undermines the UX design for the `<PinnedItems>` slotfill and area, which is intended to show buttons for functionality which the user explicitly opts in to. Thus, were this to be distributed in a plugin, it would be a good idea to associate it with a toggleable editor setting.

Comment: where should the code be added? I added it into my custom plugin, but it doesn't work

Comment: Hello. Do you mind if I remind you about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugin "Simple Custom CSS and JS" and make sure to have only checked the box "In Admin" and you see the old "Preview" that directly opens the post/page preview in a new tab :-)